# Spring Roo v.s. Maven 2 Archetypes

Tags: maven-2, spring-roo, archetypes

I want to implement a tool that generates web service application, based on a WSDL file. The idea is to ask the user questions and to generate an application with features based on those questions. The generated application will not need any of the existing `Spring Roo` modules like `addon-jpa` or `addon-security`. 
I considered `Spring Roo` for this task, but the same can be achieved with `Maven 2 archetypes`.

What are the pros/cons of using `Spring Roo` compared to `Maven 2 archetypes` for such a task? What is the real added value of `Spring Roo`? Would would be simpler to use, `Spring Roo API` or the `Maven 2 archetypes API`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

very old thread...

I would be prefer using Maven 2 archetypes. Very straight forward.. within minutes you would get starting deploying application in tomcat/glassfish web container..

Maven also help managing libs versioning..